# Issue with Print Preview in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, printing, scaling, preview

http://forefronttechnologies.net/necrotic/onlinereg.php

Here's the website in question.

The problem is as follows. I would like it to scale to the entire paper and not just a small portion of the paper. I have set the wrapper, main div, and right side div in INCHES to accommodate for paper size. Unfortunately it only fits the entire paper when I make the widths too big and they have to wrap down to a second piece of paper(which I would like to avoid.)

I would like to print this page on one paper, both divs, side by side, without the print preview scaling it down to some small portion of the entire paper.

Comment: What happens if you set the widths in percentages? In my mind at least, it would then print it to x% of total printable area.

Comment: Just changed them to percentages, didn't work. :(

Comment: Percentages, EMs, inches, nothing worked so far.